# Vue 3: defineAsyncComponent not resolving .vue files and not splitting chunks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-component

I'm trying to load Vue 3 components in a asynchronous way. I've found that there is a function called

```
defineAsyncComponent
```

which is supposed to be used as follows:

```
const GameUI = defineAsyncComponent(()=>import(filePath));
app.component("GameUI", GameUI);
```

filePath in this context is exactly: `'./components/GameUI/GameUI.element.vue'`

Running the app like this leads to the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './components/GameUI/GameUI.element.vue'
    at eval (eval at ./src lazy recursive)
```

But... if I change the `filePath` code to import the path as a string:

```
const GameUI = defineAsyncComponent(()=>import('./components/GameUI/GameUI.element.vue'));
```

The app works, it does find the component.

I don't want to use constant strings, because I have a lot of components and I want to load them asynchronously.

One of my main goals to achieve this, is to load the webapp by parts, component by component whenever they are needed, instead of loading them all on start.

I've also find that if I append a comment as follows:

```
const GameUI = defineAsyncComponent(()=>import(/* webpackChunkName: "GameUI" */ './components/GameUI/GameUI.element.vue'));
```

The JavaScript part for the GameUI component, should have it's own `chunk.js` file, but I always keep getting everything in a couple `.js` chunk files, which **contradicts** the async loading I want to achieve.

I'm using `vue-cli-service`, and my **vue.config.js** looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false,
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
        sass: {
          additionalData: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
            ? '$baseURL:"/dist/";'
            : '$baseURL:"/";'
        }
    }
      },
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? '/dist/'
  : '/',
    devServer: {
      https: true,
      port:"",
      host:'website.com',
      disableHostCheck: true,
      cert: (fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')+""),
      key: (fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem')+""),
      ca: (fs.readFileSync('ca.pem')+""),
    }
  };
```

I've already tried multiple stuff I've found online, but they are not that much explanatory. I'm literally doing the same as some online articles I've found and cannot find the problem on my side.

The two main problems are:

- Cannot load **.vue** files from variables, only full strings.
- Cannot **split** the code into different .js files for every async loaded component.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing cannot work because you are using a `variable` as value to `defineAsyncComponent`.

According to the [limitations of async import](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations), you cannot import your component usinig a variable. Instead what you can do is:

```js
// If the component name to call is GameUI.element
const component = 'GameUI.element' // can be comed from anyting
const GameUI = defineAsyncComponent(()=>import(`./components/GameUI/${component}.vue`));

app.component("GameUI", GameUI);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first question:
Because there have some [limitations of async import](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations)
.

Comment: Will try that for the first problem. Do you have any idea what’s going on for the second problem? To split the code in chunks.

Comment: Certainly, I don't know about that. But do you hear about Separation of Concerns? Maybe it's help for you to get the answer, that separate these two loosely related problem.